# MBProgressHUD crash in [MBProgressHUD done]

Tags: ios, objective-c, mbprogresshud

I am using the MBProgressHUD in my app. I always receive crash logs about it by crash reporter system, just like that

```
Cloudoc-Patient -[MBProgressHUD done] (MBProgressHUD.m:376)
1devices
App Version: -
Thread 0 Crashed:
0 libobjc.A.dylib 0x197350000 + 113616
1 Cloudoc-Patient -[MBProgressHUD done] (MBProgressHUD.m:376)
2 UIKit 0x18a0f0000 + 295108
3 UIKit 0x18a0f0000 + 294860
4 QuartzCore 0x189a2c000 + 87596
5 libdispatch.dylib 0x1979d4000 + 6484
6 libdispatch.dylib 0x1979d4000 + 25100
7 CoreFoundation 0x18555c000 + 914756
8 CoreFoundation 0x18555c000 + 906732
9 CoreFoundation 0x18555c000 + 36724
10 GraphicsServices 0x18efb4000 + 46844
11 UIKit 0x18a0f0000 + 486804
12 Cloudoc-Patient main (main.m:23)
13 libdyld.dylib 0x197a00000 + 10760
```

In the Xcode-->Organizer-->Crashes, after locating the code, it like that[crash code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gs5eh.jpg)
I use it just like that in a UIViewController category

```
- (void)showLoadingHUD {
if(!self.view)
{
    return;
}
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
hud.removeFromSuperViewOnHide = YES;
hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
}
- (void)hideHUD {
if(!self.view)
{
    return;
}
[MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:NO];
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try to set exception breakpoint and run the app. When app stops on breakpoint check that all related to progress hud views still exists.

Comment: deallocated instance and you still trying to call a method on progresshud? just a guess

Comment: @Joshua,you mean the exception type is 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS', the progresshud instance has already been deallocated, I still access it?

Comment: @Evgeniy Gushchin,I am not sure when the exception can happen, I can not reproduce it

Answer (score 0):

My way to use:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) MBProgressHUD *hud;
```

And then

```
#pragma mark - DataManager -
- (void)getData {

if (![self.hud isHidden]) {
    [self.hud hideAnimated:YES];
}
self.hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

[XXXDataManager xxxWithRequestModel:self.xxxRequestModel completion:^(BOOL success, id  _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    [self.hud hideAnimated:YES];

    if (success) {
        ...
    }
    else {
        ...
    }
}];}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think when the hud was added to self.view, it had been refered  strongly by self(because self refer to view strongly).Why do you refer to hud by a strong property?